# Get a frequency count based on multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have the following dataframe.

| Group | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Short | Small |
| Short | Small |
| Moderate | Medium |
| Moderate | Small |
| Tall | Large |

I want to count the frequency of how many times the same row appears in the dataframe.

```
Group           Size      Time
Short          Small        2
Moderate       Medium       1 
Moderate       Small        1
Tall           Large        1
```

Comment: Note on performance, including alternatives: [Pandas groupby.size vs series.value_counts vs collections.Counter with multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328246/pandas-groupby-size-vs-series-value-counts-vs-collections-counter-with-multiple)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can use groupby's [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# load the sample data
data = {'Group': ['Short', 'Short', 'Moderate', 'Moderate', 'Tall'], 'Size': ['Small', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Large']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Option 1:

```py
dfg = df.groupby(by=["Group", "Size"]).size()

# which results in a pandas.core.series.Series
Group     Size
Moderate  Medium    1
          Small     1
Short     Small     2
Tall      Large     1
dtype: int64
```

Option 2:

```py
dfg = df.groupby(by=["Group", "Size"]).size().reset_index(name="Time")

# which results in a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
      Group    Size  Time
0  Moderate  Medium     1
1  Moderate   Small     1
2     Short   Small     2
3      Tall   Large     1
```

Option 3:

```py
dfg = df.groupby(by=["Group", "Size"], as_index=False).size()

# which results in a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
      Group    Size  Time
0  Moderate  Medium     1
1  Moderate   Small     1
2     Short   Small     2
3      Tall   Large     1
```

Answer (score 96):

***Update*** after pandas 1.1 `value_counts` now accept multiple columns

```
df.value_counts(["Group", "Size"])
```

---

You can also try `pd.crosstab()`

```
Group           Size

Short          Small
Short          Small
Moderate       Medium
Moderate       Small
Tall           Large

pd.crosstab(df.Group,df.Size)


Size      Large  Medium  Small
Group                         
Moderate      0       1      1
Short         0       0      2
Tall          1       0      0
```

---

EDIT: In order to get your out put

```
pd.crosstab(df.Group,df.Size).replace(0,np.nan).\
     stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Time'})
Out[591]: 
      Group    Size  Time
0  Moderate  Medium   1.0
1  Moderate   Small   1.0
2     Short   Small   2.0
3      Tall   Large   1.0
```

Comment: nice. you can even add `margins=True` to get the marginal counts!

Comment: Also df.value_counts(["Group", "Size"]).reset_index() will turn it into a dataframe

Comment: As you count all columns, you can use `df.value_counts()`.

Answer (score 5):

Other posibbility is using [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and `aggfunc='size'`

```
df_solution = df.pivot_table(index=['Group','Size'], aggfunc='size')
```