# Group by two columns and count the occurrences of each combination in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'user_id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2','a2','a2','a3','a3','a3'], 'product_id' : ['p1','p1','p2','p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p3']})

product_id  user_id
    p1       a1
    p1       a1
    p2       a1
    p1       a2
    p1       a2
    p1       a2
    p2       a3
    p2       a3
    p3       a3
```

in real case there might be some other columns as well, but what i need to do is to group by data frame by product_id and user_id columns and count number of each combination and add it as a new column in a new dat frame

output should be something like this:

```
user_id product_id  count
a1       p1            2
a1       p2            1
a2       p1            3
a3       p2            2
a3       p3            1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
grouped=data.groupby(['user_id','product_id']).count()
```

but the result is:

```
user_id product_id
 a1       p1
          p2
 a2       p1
 a3       p2
          p3
```

actually the most important thing for me is to have a column names count that has the number of occurrences , i need to use the column later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: get a frequency count based on two columns (variables) in pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271098/python-get-a-frequency-count-based-on-two-columns-variables-in-pandas-datafra)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'user_id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2','a2','a2','a3','a3','a3'], 'product_id' : ['p1','p1','p2','p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p3']})
>>> count_series = data.groupby(['user_id', 'product_id']).size()
>>> count_series
user_id  product_id
a1       p1            2
         p2            1
a2       p1            3
a3       p2            2
         p3            1
dtype: int64
>>> new_df = count_series.to_frame(name = 'size').reset_index()
>>> new_df
  user_id product_id  size
0      a1         p1     2
1      a1         p2     1
2      a2         p1     3
3      a3         p2     2
4      a3         p3     1
>>> new_df['size']
0    2
1    1
2    3
3    2
4    1
Name: size, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes ,very close , but how can i have them in a new dataframe especially those size number as a column name for example 'size'?

Comment: actually i have R background and this task can be easily done using dplyr summaries and count()

Answer (score 9):

In *Pandas 1.1.0* you can use the method `value_counts` with DataFrames:

```
df.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
product_id  user_id
p1          a2         3
p2          a3         2
p1          a1         2
p3          a3         1
p2          a1         1
```

If you need a DataFrame:

```
df.value_counts().to_frame('counts').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  product_id user_id  counts
0         p1      a2       3
1         p2      a3       2
2         p1      a1       2
3         p3      a3       1
4         p2      a1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a little on @Nehal's response if you want to create another column with the results combined:

you can combine the product_id and size columns:

```
new_df['combo'] = new_df['product_id'].map(str) + '(' + new_df['size'].map(str) +')'
```

...and then use groupby again to organize that column by 'user_id'

```
new_df['combo'].astype(str).groupby(new_df['userid']).agg(['size',', '.join])
```