# New to Pandas Use of pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

```
Products Months  
A         12 
B         11
C         8
A         11
A         11
C         8
B         12
```

Above is my dataframe and I want following output using pandas

```
Months     8   11   12
Products   
A          0   2    1
B          0   1    1
C          2   0    0
```

I am new to pandas. How can I get above output using Pivot table? or any other method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271098/python-get-a-frequency-count-based-on-two-columns-variables-in-pandas-datafra

Comment: The canonical pivot answer by @piRSquared : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe